# Returning all results as a row

Tags: sqlite

I'm working with Sqlite3, and I'm a little stumped at how to build strings with a given set of data.  What I would like is to get every tag from a given item without having a bunch of rows to deal with.

```
SELECT i.item, t.tag
    FROM items i 
    LEFT JOIN tags t
         ON i.id=t.item
    WHERE i.id=:id;
```

Returns a table like:

```
 | item6 | tag1 |
 | item6 | tag2 |
```

Preferred format:

```
| item6 | tag1, tag2, tag3 |
```

Comment: If the item is GIVEN (and you said it was in the question), why are you selecting it? Select only the tags if that is what you want.

Comment: In this usage case, I don't necessarily have the name (as well as some other info) of the item, just it's ID.  I was hoping to get both from a single select.

Comment: @John: The outer shell?

Comment: Nevermind. I see where your parameter is now. Retracted my last comment. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT i.item,
       group_concat(t.tag)
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON i.id = t.item
WHERE i.id = :id
GROUP BY i.item
```

For a small query like this, performance does not matter, but if you think that a join and a GROUP BY are overkill, try something like this:

```
SELECT item,
       (SELECT group_concat(tag)
        FROM tags
        WHERE item = :id)
FROM items
WHERE id = :id
```